# Restricting a trait to objects?

Tags: scala, traits, singleton-type

Is there a way to restrict a trait so that it can only be mixed into objects? E.g.

```scala
trait OnlyForObjects {
  this: ... =>
}

object Foo extends OnlyForObjects  // --> OK

class Bar extends OnlyForObjects   // --> compile error
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes! There's the obscure and mostly undocumented `scala.Singleton`:

```
scala> trait OnlyForObjects { this: Singleton => }
defined trait OnlyForObjects

scala> object Foo extends OnlyForObjects
defined module Foo

scala> class Bar extends OnlyForObjects
<console>:15: error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type Bar does not conform to OnlyForObjects's selftype OnlyForObjects
 with Singleton
       class Bar extends OnlyForObjects
                         ^
```

It's mentioned a few times in the [language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), but doesn't even appear in the API documentation.

Comment: Ha!  I've come to expect totally insane and amazing answers from you that use crazy language features, but I see now we've moved on to *secret* features.

Comment: That _Yes!_ eta-expands to _finally somebody has asked this!_.

Comment: do you know why it is working in the scala file, but it fails on worksheet ?