# What can I use scala.Singleton for?

Tags: scala

To clarify: I am NOT asking what I can use a Singleton design pattern for. The question is about largely undocumented trait provided in scala.

What is this trait for? The only concrete use case I could find so far was to limit a trait to objects only, as seen in this question: [Restricting a trait to objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25406698/restricting-a-trait-to-objects)

This question sheds some light on the issue [Is scala.Singleton pure compiler fiction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118038/is-scala-singleton-pure-compiler-fiction), but clearly there was another use case as well!

Is there some obvious use that I can't think of, or is it just mainly compiler magicks?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I disagree, neither is it off topic (Scala), nor broad (it's very specific), nor opinion based (it's asking for use cases), and clearly a question ("what can you use the synthetic trait `Singleton` for?")

Comment: "clearly there was another use case as well" - Where did you gather that from?

Comment: @0__ I was referring to the question linked, restricting the trait to objects only

Comment: I'm with @0__, and just voted to reopen. I can imagine exactly what a good answer to this question would look like (although I don't have time to write it at the moment). Sometimes I don't understand the Stack Overflow police.

Comment: Seconded for reopening, I'm also interested in a possible response.

Comment: @TravisBrown if at some point you have the time, it would be nice to know what you think about this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question is answered by Martin Odersky's comment on the [mailing list thread](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-Singleton-td1940630.html) linked to from the linked question:

> The type Singleton is essentially an encoding trick for existentials
>   with values. I.e.
>
> ```
> T forSome { val x: T }
> ```
>
> is turned into
>
> ```
> [x.type := X] T forSome { type X <: T with Singleton }
> ```
>
> Singleton types are usually not used directly…

In other words, there is no intended use beyond guiding the typer phase of the compiler. The Scala Language Specification has this bit in §3.2.10, also [§3.2.1](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#singleton-types) indicates that this trait might be used by the compiler to declare that a type is stable.

---

You can also see this with the following (Scala 2.11):

```
(new {}).isInstanceOf[Singleton]

<console>:54: warning: fruitless type test: a value of type AnyRef cannot also
                       be a Singleton
              (new {}).isInstanceOf[Singleton]
                                   ^
res27: Boolean = true
```

So you cannot even use that trait in a meaningful test.

(**This is not a definite answer, just my observation**)

Comment: It can actually be useful when dealing with path dependent types—[here's an example](https://gist.github.com/travisbrown/2bcee3650447094059e2) I ran into just last week.

Comment: @TravisBrown It's great to see an example and still not having a single clue what is going on. :(

Comment: @Kigyo: Yeah, sorry, that gist needs some context that I don't have the energy to write up right now.

Comment: @TravisBrown Take your time. You have my attention.